# Git does not detect new files

Tags: eclipse, git

According to my Eclipse I am working in `develop` branch.

This is my git status

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But listing the files, there are files that are present in my project but not in the branch that I would like to add them

```
 git ls-files
```

I've also created a new Java file in Eclipse and is not detected for git

Comment: I do not know, maybe those files are listed in .gitignore?

Comment: Are you sure the files are not in `.gitignore`?

Comment: no, normal java files

Comment: Check in `.git/info/exclude` as well as `.gitignore`.

Comment: Did you add the Java file with the git add command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see files under `git ls-files` and they don't show under `git status` then probably they are already inside the index, and - most likely - commited.

You can use `git cat-file -p HEAD:filename` to check content of object in the repository.

My guess is that you have assume-unchanged (this prevents any changes to show up in status) or skip-worktree flags set inside index. You can check it via `git ls-files -v file`. If in first column you see:

- lovercase letter it means you have assume-unchanged flag set as true: `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged file` should help.
- `S` or `s` you have skip-worktree flag set as true, and unsetting it should help: `git update-index --no-skip-worktree file`
- if you see `H` it means that file has been commited and it has not been modified.

There's also a possibility that your's index is corrupted, you could try `git update-index --really-refresh` or deleting .git/index (Git should recreate that for you when necessary)